# Product of subgroups and generating sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Prove or disprove the following:

$(1)$ Let $H$,$K$ be subgroups of a finite group $G$. If $|HK|=|\langle H,K \rangle|$, then $HK=\langle H,K \rangle$, that is, $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$.

$(2)$ Let $H_{1}$,$H_{2}$,..., $H_{n}$ be subgroups of a finite group $G$, where $n$ is a positive intger. If $|H_{1}H_{2}...H_{n}|=|\langle H_{1},H_{1},...,H_{n} \rangle|$, then $H_{1}H_{2}...H_{n}=\langle H_{1},H_{1},...,H_{n} \rangle$, that is, $H_{1}H_{2}...H_{n}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

My try:

$(1)$ $HK$ is a subset of $\langle H,K \rangle$. Since $|HK|=|\langle H,K \rangle|$ and $\langle H,K \rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $HK=\langle H,K \rangle$.

$(2)$ Same as in $(1)$.

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber: Please see the question again.

Comment: Looks correct to me.  Good job.